# Split a string by comma in excluding braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very much new to regex and I have a requirement to split a string by comma and generate a array out of it. Any pointer will be really helpful.

In my result array should have 3 item and all nested comma inside {} and () need to be ignored split should be done only on outer comma. Refer the output image [image]

I have tried below regex in javascript but it is not solving problem completly

```
,(?!\[^{\[('\]\*\[}\])'\])/g
```

**Actual string**

```
let mystr =`attrs :{id:'hello'},ojComponent: {component:'Button', display: 'icons', chroming: 'half', icons: {start:'cartWedgitIcon', end: null}, label: $module.cartBtnLabel}, visible:('true',condition)`;
let arrayofItem = mystr.split(\<\<Regex\>\>);
```

**Expected output
**

[image]

Comment: Given that you appear to be parsing structured JSON-like data, regex is almost certainly the wrong tool for the job.  What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: My actual requirements is create a JSON object out of but, the problem here is we don't have double quote for the key attributes because of which JSON parsing is getting failed, so I was trying to split individual attributes and converting it to JSON object manually

Comment: Gotcha! With that context this question makes much more sense, thank you for explaining @Umesh!

Comment: What if a string contains braces and quotes: `start: '}\','` Yikes!  This is not a job for a regular expression--too much context with the syntax that is likely permissible.  It's a job for parser.  Typically if structured data needs to be parsed we make arrangements for it to be formatted as JSON. Why are you trying to find commas? Why are you trying to parse what looks like fragments of JavaScript?  That's typically something authors of compilers do.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Comment: Thanks Wyck , for the pointer I have written my owner parser to convert data into JSON object

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you trying to get firstly pure words out of context by implementing regular expression. Then, because in JSON every word including keys and values demand to be wrapped by single or double quotes, you may add it after getting each word inside an array function. You should use array methods to work on each word. Code sample I may suggest to use is below.

`const regX = /[a-zA-Z]+/; let matched = yourString.match(regX);`

P.S. Don't forget to retain true and false words out of context as they aren't wrapped inside quotes.